# Problem with passing object as an argument to createProcess

Tags: c++, bluetooth, createprocess, nxt

I am trying to correct a program that makes to other programs with the `createProces` call.

The problem is when I pass an object of the `Brick` class as a parameter of the `createProcess` call.

I create the object (in the main) this way:

```
char IpApplicationName[1000];

STARTUPINFO StartInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo;

strcpy(IpApplicationName, "c:\\Documents and Settings\\Eigenaar\\Bureaublad\\BluetoothTestr\\recvProc\\bin\\Debug\\recvProc.exe");

//set up the NXT
Connection *connection = new Bluetooth();
Brick *nxt = new Brick(connection);
char *nxt_ptr = (char *)&nxt;
```

Then I connect like this (`6` is the comm port of the bluetooth dongle):

```
connection->connect(6);

CreateProcess(IpApplicationName, nxt_ptr, NULL, NULL, FALSE,    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL,     &StartInfo, &ProcessInfo);
```

This all works fine I think, but the problem is when I cast the `char*` back to the `Brick` class in the `recvProc.exe` process like this:

```
Brick *nxt = (Brick*)argv[0];
```

If I comment this,  then the program works fine... What is wrong with this line? Or do I need to pass the Connection object in `createProcess`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing, as a command line argument, a *pointer to a pointer to a class*. This is broken in quite a few ways:

- CreateProcess's lpCommandLine argument takes a text string. There cannot be embedded NUL bytes. There must be a NUL byte to mark the end of the string. No such guarentee is present with a pointer-to-a-pointer, or indeed with a pointer or *any sort of non-text-data in general*.
- Even if the pointer, by some miracle, was passed properly to the new process, the new process has its own address space. It cannot use pointers from the old process, at all; they are meaningless in a process different from that which they were created. So the argument is meaningless.
- Even if it could access the old process's address space, there is nothing stopping the pointed-to brick from being destroyed before the new process completes its work.
- Even if all these were fixed, you're passing a pointer-to-a-pointer-to-a-brick, and trying to use it as a regular pointer-to-a-brick.

In short, you can't pass objects as command-line arguments. Only text.

So, what do do here? Here are your options:

- Have the child process connect to the brick on its own. Don't try to pass it a connection.
- Set up a protocol of some sort (over stdin/stdout, or possibly DCOM) to allow the child process to remote control the Brick object in the parent.
- Make `recvProc` into a DLL that runs inside the parent process.

Comment: Thansk for the feedback! There is only one problem, i can't make a "dual" connection with the same bluetooth node. So i can have 1 process connect with the nxt but i cant connect another 1 at the same time(so no to proccesses can connect to 1 node). Or is there a work around for this>(maby with semaphores?)

Comment: So you'll have to have one of the processes control the connection, and work out some method for the other processes to ask the controlling process to talk to the nxt for them.